# Integrate Django application with android

Tags: android, integrate

I have to integrate a python based (server based) HR system  with an android application . Please help with some suggestions on how to do it . I have to allow employees to mark attendance from the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to expose a rest api and interact with that from android.

For the server side you can check [django piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) while for the client side I recommend [robospice library](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice)